# Releasing file lock in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

I have a Qt program that works on Linux but not on Windows. It progressively downloads something from the internet, writes that into the file, and then tries to open that file using  QDesktopServices::openUrl. This works fine under Linux (Fedora), but when I run under Windows, nothing happens - the file is never opened, but also no error is reported.

However if I try to manually open the downloaded file on Windows, I find the reason for this. I get the error `Another program is currently using this file`, meaning that Qt has not released its lock on the file. However I have already called file->close() on it.

**How can I ensure that all locks on a QFile have been released?**

Here's a fragment of code that runs after the file has been written:

```
QString filename = file->fileName();

if (!file->flush())
  emit error("Could not finish writing file") // Not emitted
file->close();

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));
```

Comment: Have you tested the result of your operations (flush, close) for errors ?

Comment: Try if deleting the file object helps. IIRC that was necessary at some point in the past at least.

Comment: close() implies flush(), so the explicit flush() shouldn’t be necessary

Comment: @Ilya I added an error check for this, but the error is never signaled:   
`if (!file->flush()) emit error("Could not finish writing file");file->close();`

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Indeed it seems that deleting the QFile pointer has something to do with it because when I delete the QDialog that owns the QFile, the lock is removed. However calling `delete file;` doesn't solve the lock.

Comment: @Miguel I reformatted the code a bit, roll back / re-edit if you'd like it another way

Comment: @Miguel: That's very strange. Btw, I'd create the QFile on the stack. Avoids possible leaks, and you could put in an extra block or function, and call openUrl() only once that function/block is left.

Comment: I can't allocate it on the stack because it's being written to asynchronously. It's progressively downloaded using QNetworkAccessManager#get, and only closed once the download is finished

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a Qt issue. I have seen similar behaviour on Windows systems before (with and without Qt), it might be that either the CRT or the OS still haven't finished their work on the file. 
You might try to disable disk write caching in the OS to see, if things work as expected. I had to do this in a Windows-Embedded RT environment to get deterministic behaviour.

BTW: You can evaluate QFile::error() even after calling QFile::close() so you can skip your flush part completely.